# how to display image under horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have created a horizontal scrollview in android, which scrolls through images. I would like to display text underneath each image, but i can only seem to display the text on the image or to the right of it no matter what i do. for example whenever i use the android:layout_below command the text just disappears altogether. does anyone know why this happens and how i can make it show under the image properly?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.selwyn.ciaran.cookbook.IngredientsActivity">


    <include android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Ingredients"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_below ="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:measureAllChildren="false"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/_linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My cell.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/_imageName"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My ingredients activity

```
public class IngredientsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout mainLayout;

    private int[] ingredients;
    private int[] images = {R.drawable.oj, R.drawable.oj, R.drawable.oj,
            R.drawable.oj, R.drawable.oj, R.drawable.oj, R.drawable.oj};

    private View cell;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredients);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id._linearLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

            cell = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
            text = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id._imageName);
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id._image);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // do whatever you want ...
                    Toast.makeText(IngredientsActivity.this,
                            (CharSequence) imageView.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            imageView.setTag("Image#" + (i + 1));



            imageView.setImageResource(images[i]);
            text.setText("Image#" + (i + 1));

            mainLayout.addView(cell);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You set fixed height to HorizontalScrollView instead give it to the image view (In My cell.xml file) and try and make HorizontalScrollView height to wrap_content.

Comment: can you post an image how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Include your `cell.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/_linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  //<----here
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  //<---here
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <include layout="@layout/cell"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your `cell.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/_imageName"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="dummy"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When including in your `HorizontalLayout`, your view will be matched automatically: [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use modified xml files

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:text="Ingredients"
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  <HorizontalScrollView
      android:layout_below ="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:measureAllChildren="false"
      android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/_linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

      <include layout="@layout/cell"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

cell.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_imageName"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="dummy"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```